# usr/bin/X11 has too many recursive symbolic link

Tags: linux, x11, symlink, dir

I just want to know why. I know its known only to linux devs. But why usr/bin/X11 has too many symbolic links. If I type in command cd usr/bin then use 'tab', it shows X11 and it goes on to subdirectory X11 (inside and inside and so on) until say 40th subdir. And when I'm in 40th subdir and go to X11 and tap 'tab' again X11/X11/X11 and so on upto 40th. When I press 'enter' here, I've been redirected to usr/bin itself. What sort of behaviour is this and why?

Comment: This simply looks like a recursive link, so a link pointing to itself (probably `X11->/usr/bin/X11`). Whilst it is valid and works, it still makes sense to limit applications when following such links, otherwise this would result in an out-of-memory error later or worse.

Comment: I just thought its quite queer to point itself n times. So no actual reason and its just simply???

Comment: Looks like this is a setup Ubuntu chose, this differs from all other distributions I checked this against. I have no idea _why_ they do that. You'd have to ask them, I'd say....

Comment: Thats what I thought while posting this. :) Thanks @arkascha (y)

Comment: Actually I have to revise my statement :-) Seems the motivation was to keep backwards compatibility for some applications traditionally kept in `/usr/bin/X11` (back in time when X11 still was some brand new addition, I guess). Those applications are now kept in `/usr/bin` confirming with the standard file system layout. So for older, hard wired path settings this symbolic link `/usr/bin/X11 -> /usr/bin` established backwards compatibility.

Comment: Apparently the setup has first been established by the openSUSE distribution (as far as I could find out). Indeed the openSUSE distribution has a much longer history than Ubuntu and certainly was very active and innovative back then. This has changed after Novell has been slit up, obviously. So I assume Ubuntu has just silently accepted the setup alongside many other details.

Answer (score 2):

The X Window System used to store its executables in /usr/bin/X11. They were later consolidated into `/usr/bin/`. The old location is symlinked to the new location to retain backwards compatibility.